# Matrix over -1/2

Tags: matrices, covariance

I know what is inverse (-1) of a  matrix but I do not have any idea how to compute this P^{-1/2}.

[image]

Comment: @DietrichBurde, no it is not dublicate of that question because square root means 1/2, what I ask here is -1/2

Comment: @ilhan: Invert the square root, or square root the inverse.

Comment: Use the spectral decomposition.

Comment: I am trying now, I will get results in a moment.

Comment: @user2357112, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Square Root of a $2x2$ Matrix

To quote from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix) Wikipedia article, for a $2x2$ matrix $M$ with
$$
M = \left( \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ C & D \end{array}\right)
$$
one defines
$$
\tau = \mbox{tr} \, M = A + D, \quad
\delta = \mbox{det} \, M = AD - BC
$$
and
$$
s = \pm \sqrt{\delta}, \quad t = \pm \sqrt{\tau + 2 s}
$$

Which for $t \ne 0$ yields
$$
M^{1/2} = \frac{1}{t} \left(
\begin{array}{cc} A + s & B \\ C & D + s \end{array}
\right)
$$

### 2. Inverse of a $2x2$ Matrix

The inverse of a $2x2$ matrix using the above definitions for $M$ and $\delta$ is

$$
M^{-1} = \frac{1}{\delta} \left(
\begin{array}{cc} D & -B \\ -C & A & \end{array}
\right)
$$

### 3. Combining both to get $M^{-1/2}$

$$
M^{-1/2} = (M^{-1})^{1/2} = (M^{1/2})^{-1} 
$$

Using the latter one we get

$$
M^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\delta'} \left(
\begin{array}{cc} D' & -B' \\ -C' & A' & \end{array}
\right) =
\frac{1}{\delta' t} \left(
\begin{array}{cc} D + s & -B \\ -C & A + s & \end{array}
\right) 
$$
with $\delta' = ((A+s)(D+s) - BC) / t^2$.

### 4. Test with the Example given

$$
A = 1, \quad B = 0.4, \quad  C = 0.4, \quad D = 1
$$

we get (rounded to 5 digits) for the matrix roots:

$$
\tau = 2, \quad \delta = 0.84 \\
s = \pm 0.91652, \quad t \in \{\pm 1.9578, \pm 0.40862 \} \\
M^{1/2} \in \left\{ 
\pm \left(
\begin{array}{cc} 0.97891 & 0.20431 \\ 0.20431 & 0.97891 \end{array}
\right),
\pm \left(
\begin{array}{cc} 0.20431 & 0.97891 \\ 0.97891 & 0.20431 \end{array}
\right)  
\right\}
$$

and for the inverse matrix roots:

$$
\delta' \in \{ 0.91652, -0.91652 \} \\
M^{-1/2} \in \left\{ 
\pm\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 1.06807 & -0.22292 \\ -0.22292 & 1.06807 \end{array}
\right),
\pm\left(
\begin{array}{cc} -0.22292 & 1.06807 \\ 1.06807 & -0.22292 \end{array}
\right)
\right\}
$$

That first positive one is the one from your example. Testing a bit:

$$
(M_1^{-1/2})^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 1.06807 & -0.22292 \\ -0.22292 & 1.06807 \end{array}
\right)^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 1.19048 & -0.47619 \\ -0.47619 & 1.19048 \end{array}
\right) \\
M^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 1.19048 & -0.47619 \\ -0.47619 & 1.19048 \end{array}
\right)
$$
which seems fine.